# Can you encapsulate multi case discriminated unions?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I see that you can [enforce constructor usage](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/) of single-case discriminated unions, can you do the same with multi-case?

for example

```
type MemberId = 
  | MemberId of int
  | MemberGuid of Guid
```

I'm currently trying in the `fsi` like this

```
val create : int -> T option
val create : Guid -> T option
```

but I'm guessing like C#, F# won't allow you to overload based on return type for the unwrap:

```
val value : T -> string
```

**Edit ---------------**

MemberId.fsi =

```
module MemberId
open System
type _T

val createId : int -> _T option
val createGuid : Guid -> _T option

val value : _T -> 'a
```

MemberId.fs =

```
module MemberId
open System
type _T = 
    | Id of int
    | MemberGuid of Guid

let createId id = match id with
                | x when x>0 -> Some(Id(id))
                | _ -> None
let createGuid guid = Some(MemberGuid( guid))

let value (e:_T):int = e
```

Appears to be pretty close, but the unwrapper doesn't compile and I can't seem to figure out how to write it

TestConsumer MemberIdClient.fs =

```
module MemberIdClient
open System
open MemberId

let address1 = MemberId.create(-1)
let address2 = MemberId.create(Guid.Empty)

let unwrapped1 = 
  match address1 with
  | MemberId x -> () // compilation error on 'MemberId x'
  | _ -> ()
```

Comment: So you're wanting to overload a single function name to act as the constructor for each of the DU cases?

Comment: not necessarily, just trying to find a way to have a multi-case DU where using a constructor (for validation of input) is enforced.

Comment: The union itself is the type, not each case.

Comment: @Daniel I get that, you mean the line where I said `F# won't allow you to overload based on return type for the unwrap` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed there is a way to overload with the output parameter, using some inline tricks:

```
open System

type MemberId = 
    private
    | MemberId of int
    | MemberGuid of Guid

type Create = Create with
    static member ($) (Create, id  ) = MemberId id
    static member ($) (Create, guid) = MemberGuid guid

type Value = Value with
    static member ($) (Value, d:int ) = function MemberId   id   -> id   | _ -> failwith "Wrong case"
    static member ($) (Value, d:Guid) = function MemberGuid guid -> guid | _ -> failwith "Wrong case"

let inline create x : MemberId   = Create $ x
let inline value  x : 'IntOrGuid = (Value $ Unchecked.defaultof<'IntOrGuid>) x

let a = create 1
let b = create (Guid.NewGuid())

let c:int  = value a
let d:Guid = value b
```

By doing this you can 'overload' functions, even on output parameters.

Anyway the big difference with the single case DU is that now the unwrapper is not 'safe', that's why the unwrapper makes little sense, except in some specif scenarios.

In these cases you may consider other mechanisms to unwrap the values, like exposing functions `isX` or returning options which may be complemented with an active pattern to unwrap.

Having said that, if you are only interested in 'hiding' the constructors to do some validations, but not hiding the DU you can simply shadow the constructors, here's an example:

```
open System

type T = 
    | MemberId of int
    | MemberGuid of Guid

// Shadow constructors
let MemberId  x = if x > 0 then Some (MemberId x) else None
let MemberGuid x = Some (MemberGuid x)

let a = MemberId 1
let b = MemberGuid (Guid.NewGuid())
let c = MemberId -1

// but you can still pattern match
let printValue = function
| Some (MemberId   x) -> sprintf "case 1, value is %A" x
| Some (MemberGuid x) -> sprintf "case 2, value is %A" x
| None                -> "No value"

let ra = printValue a  // "case 1, value is 1"
let rb = printValue b  // "case 2, value is 67b36c20-2..."
let rc = printValue c  // "No value"

// and if you want to use an overloaded constructor
type T with
    static member Create id   = MemberId id
    static member Create guid = MemberGuid guid

let d = T.Create 1
let e = T.Create (Guid.NewGuid())

// or using the inline trick
type Create = Create with
    static member ($) (Create, id  ) = MemberId id
    static member ($) (Create, guid) = MemberGuid guid
let inline create x : T option = Create $ x

let d' = create 1
let e' = create (Guid.NewGuid())
```

Comment: still can't seem to do a `match` statement against a value constructed with this code

Comment: Do you want to match, or use overload? Those are 2 different things. Overload is resolved at compile-time, match at run-time.

Comment: `match` gives me a compile time error saying *The union cases or fields of the type 'MemberId' are not accessible from this code location*

Comment: That makes sense. You are hiding the DU. Wasn't that your goal?

Comment: Hiding the constructor, not the DU itself

Comment: The sample code you linked hides the DU as well. Anyway if you don't want to do that I updated the answer with another scenario.

Comment: I don't follow most of this but I found that the shadowing constructors seems to work

Answer (score 5):

Functions cannot be overloaded, but methods can:

```
type MemberId = 
    private
    | MemberId of int
    | MemberGuid of Guid

    static member create id = MemberId id
    static member create guid = MemberGuid guid
```

Comment: I assume all this is for the `.fsi` part of the enforcement pair?

Comment: No, this is the implementation. You can auto-gen the .fsi file from it though.

Comment: how would I auto-gen an `fsi`?

Comment: `fsc --sig` See [compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx).

Comment: wow... without an `.fsi` at all, it appears I'm able to enforce constructor usage with what you've provided? still verifying.

Comment: Right. Making the implementation `private` has the same effect as removing it from the signature file.

Comment: having trouble consuming this... `let x = MemberId.create(1)
match x with
    | MemberId (i) -> printfn "hello int! %i" x
    | MemberId(guid) -> printfn "hello guid! %A" x` what am I doing wrong? cause now I can't match against the subtypes to decide which one I have

Comment: Yes, my previous comment isn't quite right. One difference between `private` implementation and using a signature file to do this is `private` only allows access to the implementation within the same module. A signature file would allow access throughout the assembly. Pick whichever works for your use case.

Comment: can you provide a little more detail on how to implement your solution? I've edited my question to provide the snag I've hit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the little bit of code from Gustavo's answer I needed that appears to work all by itself

```
module MemberId
open System

type MemberId = 
    | MemberId of int
    | MemberGuid of Guid

// Shadow constructors
let MemberId  x = if x > 0 then Some (MemberId x) else None
let MemberGuid x = Some (MemberGuid x)
```