# Can you unwrap Discriminated Unions without a signature file?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

[Designing with Single-Type-Case DUs](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/)
given

```
type DoB = | DoB of System.DateTime

let DoB (dt:DateTime) = // shadow constructor
    if(dt.Year>1914) // business defines what a min Date of Birth should be
    then Some(DoB dt) 
    else None
```

And I see via Answers to [wrapping Multi-case DU's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212865/can-you-encapsulate-multi-case-discriminated-unions) you can do the constructor shadowing without an `.fsi` file very easily.

By Unwrapping I mean `let value (EmailAddress e):string = e` from the article (which would have to be in the `.fsi` file or applied to this `DoB` type would look like 
`let value (DoB dob):DateTime = dob` if we had an `.fsi` file.

can you do the same somehow for unwrapping that was done with the constructor?

can I somehow define an unwrapper or augmentation of some sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you mean by unwrapping, you could use an active pattern:

```
//File1.fs
let (|DoB|) (DoB dt) = dt

//File2.fs
let dob = DoB DateTime.Now //using `DoB` "constructor" function
match dob with
| Some (DoB dt) -> //using `DoB` active pattern
    printfn "DOB: %A" dt 
| None -> 
    printfn "Not a DOB"
```

This works, without shadowing the function of the same name, because active patterns live in a separate naming scope.

Comment: so if this solution does work, it requires that consuming code be in a different file than than the declaration? and I'd be able to put my shadow constructor in `File1.fs`?

Comment: No, it's not required at all.

Comment: Your consuming code doesn't appear to ever unwrap the dob back into being a `DateTime` which is what I'm after. I can't seem to write consuming code that will compile. If your solution does provide a way to unwrap a single case DU back into the primitive or type it is based on, can you show me code that would do that?

Comment: It absolutely does. Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/03o7P9). I added a type annotation to `dt` to make it clearer.

Comment: What's the purpose of the active recognizer here? I think you don't need it at all.

Comment: @Daniel I don't understand how, or why this works, but I've confirmed it, thanks

Comment: @Gustavo: It's an unwrapper, just like your `value` function. In fact, our code is virtually equivalent. However, using an active pattern allows the unwrapping to be done within the pattern match, instead of requiring a separate call (as yours does).

Comment: This whole issue makes little sense if the union implementation isn't `private` or hidden by a signature file. The active pattern is merely a way of restoring the matching capability.

Comment: OK, I get it for those cases. But in this case is just shadowing the constructor, so you don't need it. If you remove it from the code it will still work.

Comment: The OP's question is specifically about shadowing the constructor for the purpose of augmentation.

Comment: BTW @Maslow if you are happy with Daniel's answer it seems I somehow misunderstood your question, because the shape of my unwrapper is (DU e):'T = e which I thought was you were looking for, then I will remove my answer to avoid more confusion.